# DrawerLayout stops working when fragment back stack is popped

Tags: android, android-fragments, drawerlayout, viewstub

I have a DrawerLayout connected to the ActionBar with an ActionBarDrawerToggle that stops working. I know the question about why it doesn't open has been asked 100 times but my question is a little different. **My drawer works!** Yep, you click on the hamburger and the drawer opens and closes like a champ...

The problem is that **it stops working** when I dismiss any fragment that was added to the activity. Here is the activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/renderer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_root_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        ...header stuff...

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/view_stub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        ...footer stuff...

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then the activity contains this...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);  

    mRendererLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.renderer_layout);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            mRendererLayout, 
            R.string.alert_ok,
            R.string.cancel_all
    ) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            Log.e("===", "RA.Drawer Opened ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            Log.e("===", "RA.Drawer Closed ");
        }
    }; 

    mRendererLayout.addDrawerListener( mDrawerToggle );
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.e("===", "RA.onOptionsItemSelected(): ");

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

At a few points I add various fragments to the activity with

```
addFragment( new MyFragment() );
```

Each fragment has a view with an onClick() that calls

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

It is at this point that the drawer stops working. The fragment disappears as expected and it does log "RA.onOptionsItemSelected()" when the hamburger is clicked but "RA.Drawer Opened" is no longer logged and the drawer does not open. This continues until the activity is relaunched.

To make things more complicated the activity uses a ViewStub to swap out two layouts: either a FrameLayout or a FrameLayout containing a ViewPager. Only the latter has the problem. I swap out the viewStub like this...

```
ViewStub viewStub = findViewById(R.id.view_stub);
viewStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.either_layout_here);
viewStub.inflate();
```

Swapping in this layout has no problems with the drawer.  It gets a fragment added to it via addFragment():

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Swapping in this layout, on the other hand, has the problem...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

This one does not get a fragment added to its content_frame (yet), since the ViewPager handles its fragments. That's really the only difference. For some reason popping the fragment back stack breaks the drawer button on the ActionBar.

I'm stumped. Help!